# http-server -p 8082 showing ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on angular project . I want to apply PWA (Progressive web app) to my application. Here are the commands I followed.

```
ng build --prod
cd dist/appname
http-server -p 8082
```

when I open the 127.0.0.1:8082/#/ or localhost:8082/#/ it is showing following error

**This page isn’t working localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT**

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you successfully install `http-server` globally? If not, use the following command `npm i -g http-server`.

Comment: Yes it is installed globally

Comment: Do i install specific version of @angular/pwa. I red somewhere that some version of pwa wont work .

Comment: I think the reason for http-server to break is, it's not being compatible with the latest ecstatic version. Manually downgrading the ecstatic dependency to a older version (e.g 3.3.1), in http-server's package.json would just work. Refer : https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/525#issuecomment-500662362

Answer (score 6):

`http-server` has been broken recently, you can either :

- use version 0.9.0 explicitly in your package.json (`"http-server": "0.9.0",`)
- use another package that is not based on `http-server` like @Ruina suggested

Comment: I think the reason for http-server to break is it's not being compatible with the latest ecstatic version. Manually downgrading the ecstatic dependency to a older version (e.g 3.3.1), in http-server's package.json would just work. 
Refer : [link](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/525#issuecomment-500662362)

Answer (score 5):

You have to directly call `index.html`. At least that's what worked for me just now.

Try: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html

Comment: This worked for me (albeit on port 8081) on Angular CLI 8.3.17, Angular 8.2.13, Node 10.13.0 and the latest version of http-server 6.11.3. Interestingly once I knows the site is there then it no longer seems to need the page to be specified (although I am running with PWA).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem a week or so ago. I thought i did something wrong and reinstalled http-server, tried different ports and so on. Nothing worked.

I ended up finding this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve that's similar to http-server.

It solved the problem for me, i think there is some bug on http-server latest release or on pwa / service-worker.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`http-server` newer versions are not working properly.

```
If (you want to use a newer version) {
 npm install -g http-server
 http-server --o
 http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html
} else {
  npm uninstall -g http-server //if you have already installed dependancy...
  npm install -g http-server@0.9.0
  http-server --o
  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
}
```

Note:- before doing that check your node version `node --version` && npm version `npm --version`